# HTML5 input range slider runnable track not showing on safari 8.0.5

Tags: css, html, safari

Does have anyone have a solution for this? I am using the -webkit prefix but no luck.

```
input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
    width: 100%;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: $blue;
    height: 1px;
    margin-top: -10px;
    border-radius: 1.3px;
    border: 0.2px solid $blue;
}
```

It's supposed to look like this:
[image]

On Safari 8.0.5 it looks like this:
[image]

Comment: What have you tried? Really difficult to answer your question without context. Thanks

Comment: @BenRondeau I have edited my question

Comment: Can you provide a runnable code snippet? Right now there is no HTML code.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with safari only css

```
_::-webkit-full-page-media, _:future, :root input[type=range] {
 width: 100%;
 cursor: pointer;
 background: $blue;
 height: 1px;
 margin-top: -10px;
 border-radius: 1.3px;
 border-top: 0.5px solid $blue;
 background-color: $blue;
}
```